# Get last segment of URL path with MVC Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I have this URL: `http://localhost:.../home/blogpost/#'I want to get this string'`

I get it when pressing:

```
<a href="/home/blogpost/#@item.Title">@item.Title</a>
```

`@item.Title` is from my database and that string will change. Now I need to get the `'I want to get this string'` string on that page so that I can do a `if` statement with it, like this:

```
@if(@item.Title == 'I want to get this string')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute (the part of an URI after the `#`) is not sent to the server when the browser retrieves the page. So, you cannot get it out of a normal GET or POST request on the server at all.

That data is available in the browser, so you could access it using javascript of even CSS.

Using ajax techniques, you could load a skeleton page and send the target string yourself to the server and have it react to it, and only then load the rest of the page. A bit overkill for most uses I'm afraid and there are drawbacks as well (e.g. search engine might have more trouble to see your content).

It's easier to send the string to the server as a GET parameter if you have the level of control you seem to have. [simply replace the `#` with a `?`], that will be sent to the server by the browser.

Do note that you should URLencode any data you add on to a URL ...

Comment: How about without the #? I was using it to avoid the %20 at spaces in my string.

Comment: And if I keep #, and use javascript for this then I have the problem of returning the string from js to my razor code where I need to get it into the if-statement. @if(@item.Title == 'I want to get this string')

Comment: `%20` is a URL encoded space. You can also encode a space as `+` in URLs. Using the # is not a good way to get data back from the browser, I'd forget that avenue. Using a GET parameter is the better approach by far. [But you have to URL encode all things not allowed in a URL ... like spaces, but there's plenty more]

Comment: You were right. I solved the issue by passing @ item.Title to my controller with @ Html.ActionLink instead and from there further on to a method where I performed my if-statement. Works like a charm.